# При запуске Flask на сайте отображает Not Found

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Когда запускаю код, консоль не ругается, никаких ошибок не отображает, перейдя по url-адресу который выдала консоль на сайте отображается **Not Found**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### **Вот что выводит консоль**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Раньше проект запускал через PyCharm, командой `flask run` в консоли, но закончился пробный период и использовать PyCharm не имею возможности, а так как у меня есть уже VS (не Visual Code), то я решил через него, но командой у меня не получается, поэтому решил через код

Какая проблема может быть в этом коде?

```
# main.py

from flask import Flask, Blueprint, render_template, request
from calculator import *
from flask_login import login_required, current_user

app = Flask(__name__)
main = Blueprint('main', __name__)


@main.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html')
    else:
        premium_value = int(request.form["premium_value"])

        plan_a1 = int(request.form["plan_a1"])
        fact_a1 = int(request.form["fact_a1"])
        plan_a2 = int(request.form["plan_a2"])
        fact_a2 = int(request.form["fact_a2"])
        plan_a3 = int(request.form["plan_a3"])
        fact_a3 = int(request.form["fact_a3"])
        plan_a4 = int(request.form["plan_a4"])
        fact_a4 = int(request.form["fact_a4"])
        result_A = list(sum_coefficient_A(coefficient_a1(plan_a1, fact_a1), coefficient_a2(plan_a2, fact_a2), coefficient_a3(plan_a3, fact_a3), coefficient_a4(plan_a4, fact_a4)))

        weight_b1 = int(request.form["weight_b1"])
        kpi_b1 = int(request.form["kpi_b1"])
        weight_b2 = int(request.form["weight_b2"])
        kpi_b2 = int(request.form["kpi_b2"])
        result_B = list(coefficient_B(weight_b1, kpi_b1, weight_b2, kpi_b2))

        weight_c1 = int(request.form["weight_c1"])
        kpi_c1 = int(request.form["kpi_c1"])
        result_C = list(coefficient_C(weight_c1, kpi_c1))

        return render_template('result.html', premiya=premiya(premium_value, result_A, result_B, result_C))


@main.route('/profile')
@login_required
def profile():
    return render_template('profile.html', name=current_user.name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

При том что когда я добавляю этот

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'main.py'
```

метод на сайте выводит text, но тот функционал, который мне нужен, не выполняется.

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.

Comment: Очевидно, `main` не подключен к `app`

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать или скажите, как правильно задать запрос в гугле